# Doesn't Xwalk (Crosswalk) have caching for offline mode?

Tags: android, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I'm using Crosswalk instead of the default Webview on Android and when I use the Webview and i enable caching, if I turn off the wi-fi the pages load from cache.
On Crosswalk I don't see this, it just displays a toast with "Unable to reach server" and that's it. How can I force XWalkView to do something this line does for normal Webviews

`webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API is not exposed yet, but we are working on this, please track the status in this JIRA:
https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-6832

Comment: Thank you. Could you do me a favor and look at this question as well, please? I'd greatly appreciate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185366/crosswalk-xwalk-pull-to-refresh-not-working