# Crosswalk (xwalk) pull to refresh not working

Tags: android, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I'm using Crosswalk (`XwalkView`) instead of the default `Webview` on Android but it seems that the defalt pull-to-refresh functionality doesn't work on Android 4.3. I've tested it on 5.0 and it's ok, but on 4.3 and 4.2.2 it doesn't work. I'm guessing it has to do with < 5.0 ?!

I've tried something like this to enable it, but it failed to work:

```
    //Disable the edge effect and try to enable pull to refresh in case we're using xwalk webviews
    if (BuildConfig.IS_XWALK) {
        final String INIT_SWITCHES[] = {"Xwalk", "--enable-pull-to-refresh-effect", "--disable-overscroll-edge-effect"};
        if (!CommandLine.isInitialized()) {
            CommandLine.init(INIT_SWITCHES);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we already have a JIRA about this feature, please track it here: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-6277.

It has some block issue before, but we will continue investigating how to implement it.